# Classification of 6-D Nilmanifolds

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, lattices-in-lie-groups

I am reading the G.Cavalcanti and M.Gualtieri's Generalized Complex Structures on Nilmanifolds. In the introduction it is said that there are 34 nilpotent lie algebra isomorphism classes. There are two references but these references are unavaliable in the web. So could someone please explain me how this classification achieved? Also, why the classification of nilpotent Lie algebras also equivalent to classification of nilmanifolds?

Thank you in advance.

Murat